# how to rewrite foreach DomDocument function using standard php regex

Tags: php, regex, foreach, replace

How would I rewrite this DomDocument php
to grab assign my array key to the proper image?
NOTE:: multiple images in $html or the_content. I need to loop thru each one.

This is the regex to find the alignment I need (the part of the css class name after the word align)
So I need either left or right depending on the css class of alignleft or alignright

```
preg_match_all('#align(.*?)(" )#si', '<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

NOTE:: it won't always be alignleft. It could be aligncenter alignnone alignright or various other class names.

I just can't figure out how to cycle thru each image and actually apply whats found to the proper image.

```
<?php

$html = '<img class="" src="xxxx" />adasdasdasd<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />';

$domdoc = new DOMDocument('');
$domdoc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($domdoc);

$imgs = $xpath->query('//img');

foreach ($imgs as $element) {

    $class = $element->getAttribute('class');

    if (strpos($class, 'alignLEFT') !== false) {

        $element->setAttribute('align', 'left');
    }

}

// DOM Document works with full html documents, so now we have to isolate our fragment

$bodyelement = $xpath->query('/html/body');
$bodyhtml = $domdoc->saveXML($bodyelement->item(0));

echo str_replace(array('<body>', '</body>'), '', $bodyhtml);
```

Comment: Why would you do something with regex if you can work in a DOM?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `$xpath->query('//img[contains(@class, \'alignLEFT\')]')`? And btw, the `align` attribute is deprecated.

Comment: See thats the thing. I CAN'T use the DOM. When I bring my email into mailchimp - it won't read any jquery or DOM modifications. I know align is depreciated and its old school. I'm using WordPress as an email template CMS. so I HAVE to have the align attribute in there for email (read: microsoft Office 2010+).